# Copy table and open a new popup window

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

I need some help from the experts here on this site.

What I would like to accomplish is, at the click of a button is to copy the existing table ('data'), open a new popup window and use the document.write to write the table from the previous page onto the new one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-ca">
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100" id="table1">
            <tr>
                <th>Fruits</th>
                <th>Vegetables</th>
                <th>Colors</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Apples</td>
                <td>Carrots</td>
                <td>red</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>0.99</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pears</td>
                <td>Celery</td>
                <td>blue</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>1.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mangos</td>
                <td>Broccoli</td>
                <td>green</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>1.50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Oranges</td>
                <td>Cauliflower</td>
                <td>purple</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>1.25</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="test it" />
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/84xkF/) is a working example.

The button needs a click handler:

```
<input type="button" value="Open popup" onclick="openPopup();" />
```

The click handler function:

```
function openPopup() {
  var popup = window.open("", "", "width=640,height=480,resizeable,scrollbars"),
      table = document.getElementById("data");

  popup.document.write(table.outerHTML);
  popup.document.close();
  if (window.focus) 
    popup.focus();
}
```

Comment: window.open will often return null

Answer (score 0):

Add onclick function for your button first:

```
  <input type="button" value="test it" onclick="openWin()" />
```

In script:

function openWin()
{

myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('data').outerHTML);

myWindow.focus();

}

Thats it.

I am not sure outerHTML property compatibility across browsers. Please check once.